# Maven : how to create project with no propagating deps?

Tags: java, maven

I have a projectX that produces as its artifact a TXT file. This is the sole artifact produced by the project. This works well. No problem.

The problem is that projects that depend on this artifact pulls with them all of projectX's artifacts which are obviously irrelevant as a TXT file doesn't have dependencies. In order to produce the TXT file projectX of course has a number of dependencies but these are irrelevant to downstream projects.

I know that I can in each individual project that uses this TXT file exclude those transitive dependencies. This is not what I want. I would like them to be stopped in projectX itself so that I do not need to declare such exclusions in each downstream project.

In my limited Maven knowledge I think I would need to look at the [scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) parameter of projectX's dependencies. I'm looking for a scope type that says : "*this dependency is required for compiling and executing projectX but it is not transitive*".  Can't find such a scope.

How can I solve this issue without messing with downstream projects ? (those that use the artifact produced by projectX)

**EDIT1**: My issue with "provided" scope is that projectX is made in such a way so that it actually executes itself as part of the build process. Admittedly this is unusual but this is what produces the TXT file which is the true output from the build. In other words: projectX's dependencies need to be available not only for projectX's *compilation* but also for projectX's *execution*, yet they must not propagate.

**EDIT2** :

How I execute the projectX itself as part of its own build process:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-txt-file</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies, also adding the project build directory -->
                    <classpath/>
                    <argument>...</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If I declare projectX's deps as `provided` then above step will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the **`provided` scope** fits your requirements. To quote from the Maven documentation you linked:

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime.[...] This scope is **only available on the compilation and test classpath**, and **is not transitive.**

(emphasis mine)

---

EDIT (after clarification in the comments and edits) : to recap, it seems the artifact in the Maven sense is not really the TXT file, at least not exclusively, and the build actually compiles some classes and runs them **within** the build.
And now, back to addressing the problem :).

The reason you're stuck is that you're arguably breaking Maven's convention of what an *artifact* is. Specifically, your project's dependencies expect that your "TXT" project is something else, and that's why your run into problems.

I see two ways out of this:

- As you mentioned in the comments, you can write a plugin that will handle the TXT file generation.
- As a quick-and-dirty solution you can:

  1. Split your project into two: a "generator" (which requires the deps) and a "holder" (which only produces and stores your TXT file).
  2. In your "generator" project, package the generator code and all its dependencies into an "uberjar" using the [assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) (deprecated apparently), or the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) (see "Examples"). Take care to specify the main class.
  3. Run `install` to include the "generator" artifact in your repo.
  4. In your "holder" project, use the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) to copy the "generator" JAR somewhere into `target`.
  5. Finally, in your "holder" project, using the `exec-maven-plugin`, execute the downloaded "generator" JAR.

Note that the second solution is basically a "poor man's plugin", so if you have more scenarios like that in your builds, learning to write Mojos would possibly provide a better payoff in the long run. Nevertheless, I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes and no. "provided" is ok from the point of view that Maven will actually try to fetch this dependency from a repository (you would think that 'provided' meant exactly that it didn't do that!) and that the dependency is not transitive. But the fact that the dep  doesn't become part of the execution class path is no-go ! It won't work !

Comment: @nolan6000 : why do you need it in the runtime (I'm assuming, since there's no "execution" classpath to my knowledge) classpath if the **only** artifact is a TXT file? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @nolan6000 : it's still unclear to me how do you "execute" a text file. Could you elaborate on your project's structure, maybe include the POM?

Comment: Have done another edit. So projectX generates a TXT file as part of its build. In order to actually generate the TXT file there needs to be an execution of the project as part of the build. I'm thinking that maybe in the true Maven way perhaps projectX should have been a Mojo (i.e. a plugin) but that seems a bit like overkill.

Comment: @nolan6000 : so it seems now that the TXT file is not really the "artifact" in the Maven sense, rather, there is a `jar` generated in the `package` phase and **that** generates the TXT file. If that is true, you can avoid creating a plugin by splitting this project into two. Regardless, it is hard to suggest a precise solution without seeing the POM in question. Can you edit it in?

Comment: Yes, projectX generates a jar for which I have no use. I don't think I even need it for the Maven Exec plugin step (see edited question) since I believe this plugin will execute off `.class` files and not off the jar. I could probably do some tricks in projectX's pom to avoid the jar file being created in the first place. Haven't done that as it has seemed like window dressing.

Comment: Btw: the TXT file **is** a true output artifact in Maven sense. I'm using the Maven Build Helper plugin to attach it as an artifact so it gets installed into repo and what have you. If it wasn't a true output artifact I wouldn't be able to create downstream deps on it.  :-)

Comment: @nolan6000 : I'd argue that your project is a bit schizophrenic on what its artifact actually is :). See the edit, I've suggested a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and comments. I have actually written a Maven plugin before. I'll accept your answer - although I wish there was another - but I do believe your answer is exhaustive and knowledgeable. I believe the basic problem I have is that in Maven world it is really only plugins that produce output artifacts. Or at least this is how it was intended. This is why I get into trouble. I still believe my world could have been a lot easier if there was more choices for `scope`. :-)

Comment: @nolan6000 : glad I helped. I really appreciate your acknowledgement and praise :). Regarding Maven: yeah, it really can't be helped, the scope you would have liked doesn't really make sense in the context of Maven's design decisions. However, I do find that Maven's rigidity is more often beneficial than hindering. And of course, there are alternatives - [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/documentation) is often touted as more "liberal", and seems to be growing in popularity lately...

Answer (score 0):

You should mark your dependencies in "ProjectX" as [optional](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html). That way, when your other projects include it, it does not resolve as a transitive dependency. :)

Scope "provided" uses a semantic that it is provided by something else (for instance a JEE  container would *provide* the servlet api).

Comment: Wauw. I must admit that this is the first time I hear of *optional dependencies*. Really embarrassing. At first look it seems to be exactly what I'm after.